# No subdirectory per git repository in Jenkins Multiple SCMs Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using two git repositories.  How do I clone each into its own subdirectory in the Jenkins workspace?  [Another user says that he can specify a subdirectory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin?focusedCommentId=60917899#comment-60917899) for each of his multiple repositories:

[image: Can specify a subdirectory]

However, in my Jenkins Job and Multijob configurations, I only see the *Advanced* options *Name* and *Refspec*:

[image: Cannot specify a subdirectory]

I am using Multiple SCMs Plugin 0.4 with Git Plugin 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

It's under Additional Behaviours - Check out to a sub-directory.

Comment: thank you, can't believe it was right under my nose this entire time

Comment: Now as Multiple SCM is depreciated is there any work around